# Make a separate row if a column contains comma-separated value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, multiple-columns

Let's suppose we have a simple select query which return result like below

```
   FirstName          LastName                     PayScale
   -----------        ------------                ---------------
    Craig              L                             150000
    Alice,Lisa         simons                        100000
```

So if we have comma-separated first name, then I want result like this

```
   FirstName          LastName                     PayScale
   -----------        ------------                ---------------
    Craig              L                             150000
    Alice              simons                        100000
    Lisa               simons                        100000
```

Comment: Just trying to learn from a scenario like this , i don't know much about sql that's why i even don't know how to do this ,

Comment: Did you try searching, at least?

Comment: yeah i do , all i know after search is that it can be done with pivot , if i am not wrong . But sadly i even don't know pivot

Comment: just trying to learn sql

Comment: Normalizing a denormalized database is typically very complicated.   Part of the reason is because every DB is different, and part of the reason is because SQL is not designed to manipulate denormalized data.  For example, there is no `Split()` function in SQL.  That's because it actually doesn't make sense to want to do that in the scope of relational algebra.  To do this, you'll often end up querying the DB and building a new table with another programming language.  So it's usually one of the most complicated things you can do because it's correcting a design mistake.

Comment: If you are trying to learn SQL, you are in the wrong place. SO is not for training in SQL

Comment: I am not learning every thing here i just stuck in a scenario and asked it here , and that is SO is for , right .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write a query as:

```
DECLARE @employee TABLE (FirstName  VARCHAR(100),
                         LastName   VARCHAR(100),
                         PayScale INT)

INSERT INTO @employee VALUES 
('Craig','L',150000) , 
('Alice,Lisa','simons',100000)



SELECT Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS FirstName  , LastName  ,PayScale
       FROM  (SELECT  CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(FirstName, ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' 
                             AS XML) AS FirstName ,  LastName    ,PayScale
               FROM  @employee) 
       AS A 
CROSS APPLY FirstName.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)
```

Comment: Perfect! Can you please add a bit description what going on

Comment: @user2413182 - check here for explanation  http://oops-solution.blogspot.in/2011/10/sql-serverhow-to-split-comma-delimited.html