# Correlation name'Split' is specified multiple times in a FROM clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to break comma seperated columns in to rows 
here is my last asked [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27498145/make-a-separate-row-if-a-column-contains-comma-separated-value)

I got solution for what i asked but suppose if i want to do this same on multiple columns

Here is what i was trying

```
SELECT OperationTypeId ,[User],[Action], 
   Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS ChangedColumns,
   Split.b.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS  OldValue, 
   Split.c.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS NewValue
   FROM  (
   SELECT  CAST ('<x>' + REPLACE(NewValue, ',', '</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML) AS NewValue ,
    CAST ('<x>' + REPLACE(OldValue, ',', '</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML) AS OldValue, 
   OperationTypeId ,[User],[Action] ,CAST ('<x>' + REPLACE(ChangedColumns, ',', '</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML) AS ChangedColumns
   FROM  AllRows)AS A
Outer APPLY ChangedColumns.nodes ('/x') AS Split(a) 
Outer APPLY OldValue.nodes ('/x') AS Split(b) 
Outer APPLY NewValue.nodes ('/x') AS Split(c)
```

it Gives error

```
The correlation name 'Split' is specified multiple times in a FROM clause.
```

Comment: I'd recommend reading the following articles: [Split strings the right way – or the next best way](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings), [Splitting Strings : A Follow-Up](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/splitting-strings-follow-up). [Splitting Strings : Now with less T-SQL](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/splitting-strings-now-with-less-t-sql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your query like this. You cannot have same correlation name to convert different columns to rows

```
SELECT OperationTypeId,
       [User],
       [Action],
       Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)')  AS ChangedColumns,
       Split1.b.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS OldValue,
       Split2.c.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS NewValue
FROM   (SELECT Cast ('<x>' + Replace(NewValue, ',', '</x><x>')
                     + '</x>' AS XML) AS NewValue,
               Cast ('<x>' + Replace(OldValue, ',', '</x><x>')
                     + '</x>' AS XML) AS OldValue,
               OperationTypeId,
               [User],
               [Action],
               Cast ('<x>'
                     + Replace(ChangedColumns, ',', '</x><x>')
                     + '</x>' AS XML) AS ChangedColumns
        FROM   AllRows)AS A
       OUTER APPLY ChangedColumns.nodes ('/x') AS Split(a)
       OUTER APPLY OldValue.nodes ('/x') AS Split1(b)
       OUTER APPLY NewValue.nodes ('/x') AS Split2(c)
```