# Make a separate row respectively if a column contains comma-separated value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I already asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27498145/make-a-separate-row-if-a-column-contains-comma-separated-value/27498371?noredirect=1#comment43428015_27498371) here but its a bit change one

```
FirstName          LastName                     PayScale
 -----------        ------------                ---------------
Alice,Lisa         simons,Jack                        100000
```

I want to see result like this

```
   FirstName          LastName                     PayScale
  -----------        ------------                ---------------
Alice              simons                        100000
Lisa               Jack                          100000
```

first value of firstname and first value of lastname will make a seperate row . In short want to comma separate multiple columns

Comment: What should happen if you have a Firstname with 2 values and a LastName with 3 values?

Comment: @BerndLinde values will always be same if first name have 2 then its sure that lastname will also have 2

Comment: [Same question by same user on the same day](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27498145/make-a-separate-row-if-a-column-contains-comma-separated-value)

Comment: @Ullas i've mentioned that i asked a question but this is change from first one

Comment: Rather than asking question after question about splitting strings, why not start reading up on database normalisation? Why not store the data in the format you require it above, then you don't need complex string manipulations at all.

Comment: How somebody have two First name and two lastName?? your db design needs attention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said by GarethD You should normalize your Database. This is a just a workaround

```
create table #test (FirstName varchar(100),LastName varchar(100),PayScale int)

insert #test values
('Alice,Lisa','simons,Jack',100000)

SELECT FirstName,
       LastName,
       b.PayScale
FROM   (SELECT Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)')FirstName,
               PayScale,
               Row_number()
                 OVER(
                   ORDER BY (SELECT 1))          rn
        FROM   (SELECT PayScale,
                       Cast ('<M>' + Replace(FirstName, ',', '</M><M>')
                             + '</M>' AS XML) AS FirstName
                FROM   #test) AS A
               CROSS APPLY FirstName.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a))fst
       JOIN (SELECT Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') LastName,
                    PayScale,
                    Row_number()
                      OVER(
                        ORDER BY (SELECT 1))           rn
             FROM   (SELECT PayScale,
                            Cast ('<M>' + Replace(LastName, ',', '</M><M>')
                                  + '</M>' AS XML) AS LastName
                     FROM   #test) AS A
                    CROSS APPLY LastName.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)) b
         ON fst.rn = b.rn
```